# Download specific part of a large zip file

Tags: python, zip, amazon-glacier

I am storing some large zip files on AWS Glacier and would like to know if its possible to download a specific file or files from the zip without downloading the whole zip?

Like if I knew that byte range 92492 to 151231 corresponded to a particular file(assuming that is even possible...),  if I download just that portion of the zip is there a way for me to extract it?

Answer (score 3):

The [central directory](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html) of a zip file is held at the very end of the file.  The very last entry in it, the *End of central directory record*, gives the offset to where this directory starts.

You can thus read the entire central directory, and search this for the filename entry you want. This entry says where the *local file header* for that file starts, and its (compressed) size. Reading that header will say where the file starts. The file may be followed by a *data descriptor*. This provides all the information needed to retrieve just that file with its header and descriptor.

Though you now have enough information to unzip the file, most tools will need a central directory that corresponds to just this file, which you will have to recreate. The man page for zip on my Fedora suggests that `zip -FF` might "fix" an archive missing the central directory.

Answer (score 1):

Python module [python-remotezip](https://github.com/gtsystem/python-remotezip) promises to do exactly this:

> access single members of a zip file archive without downloading the full content from a remote web server. For this library to work, the web server hosting the archive needs to support the range header.

It supports the same read interface as `zipfile.ZipFile`, so you can list the available files and then extract only select ones.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server, but you could pass a [byte-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests#Requesting_a_specific_range_from_a_server) parameter to the request. If the server accepts it, you are delivered the data you requested.

But i assume you wont be able to be able to extract the data.

```
import requests
url = 'http://i.imgur.com/z4d4kWk.jpg'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Range': 'bytes=1000-1023'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.headers['Content-Range'])
```

Returns:

```
bytes 1000-1023/146515
```

Comment: I know how to download a specific byte range, I am interested in associating a byte range to a specific file in the zip and extracting just the file